# How to know if a command in a pipe run successfully

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which will download git using apt and after successful download of git I want to set the config for git. I wrote a script that does the work. But I am curious to know is there a way to know that the git installation properly done or not. If git installed then i will set config otherwise I will retry or perhaps show an error message.

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read Password
echo -n Sudo Password: 
read -s password

# Run Command

setup_git_config(){
    git config --global alias.co checkout
    git config --global alias.br branch
    git config --global alias.ci commit
    git config --global alias.st status
}

install_git(){
    echo $password | sudo -S apt-get install git -y
    # here i want to check above command successfully ran or not
    setup_git_config
}

#Execute commands
install_git
```

I am asking this question because I want to write a script to install few essential program and configuration.

Updated:

```
install_git(){
    typeset ret_code
    ret_code=$?
    echo 'xyz' | sudo -S apt-get install git -y
    if [ $ret_code != 0 ]; then
        printf "Error " $ret_code
        exit $ret_code
    fi
    echo $ret_code #always echo 0
    setup_git_config
}
```

Always print 0

Comment: @DidierVanderstoken I tried but ret_code always return 0 :(. I tried with wrong password. turning off network.

Comment: $? will give you the status of last run command. If the command ran successfully then it will return 0 otherwise it will return 1. You can put an if-else condition based on the returned result.

Comment: Yes as far I understand it @Abhishek . But it always return 0. I think because of pipe, first part echo is ran successfully that's why it return 0 (not sure though). But it wasn't helpful in my case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the return code of apt-get, replace:

```
ret_code=$?
echo 'xyz' | sudo -S apt-get install git -y
```

With:

```
echo 'xyz' | sudo -S apt-get install git -y
ret_code=$?
```

The return code is available only after the command executes.  Consequently, you must capture the value of `$?` just after apt-get runs, not before it runs.

#### Notes

1. apt-get sets it return code to either 0 (success) or 100 (error).
2. Putting a password in a command, such as `echo "$password"`, means that the password will be available in plain text to anyone on the the machine who can run `ps`.  It would likely be better practice to remove the password and instead add your apt-get command to sudoers with the NOPASSWD option.

Comment: The password isn't stored in the script, that's not a problem here. But if sudo is just run once, we may just letting it ask for the password.

Comment: @hek2mgl Good point.  I should clarify:  In the 2nd version in the question, we have the command `echo 'xyz' | sudo -S apt-get install git -y` were I presume `xyz` was intended to be the password.  In the first version in the question, we have `echo $password | sudo -S apt-get install git -y` which puts the password in `ps` for anyone on the machine to see.

Comment: You are right, the second version looks like the password is stored in the script.

Comment: 2nd part is for showing that wrong password still give ret_code 0. but apparently I am stupid enough to catch ret_code before executing the command. Tanks @John1024 for pointing this out. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you.